# How to check heap size and created objects in core dump

Tags: c++, c, gdb

Since the `core file` created when the process die for any reason contains the content of the memory at that moment I suppose is possible to use `gdb` to perform some checks on the memory, but I have no idea how to use `gdb` for this.

1. is it possible to ask for the size of the heap?
2. in case the app is written in c++, is it possible to ask for the number of live instances of each class?

Regards

Comment: Plus 1 for an example use of the word "comprobation".

Comment: It is possible, but it is quite tricky to give a simple answer. There exists an open source project EZTrace http://eztrace.gforge.inria.fr/, which supplies a lot of information by translating your binary in a post-compilation stage and the information is obtained by running your process from within a process (similarly to gdb). Another starting example is the DeathHandler, https://github.com/vmarkovtsev/DeathHandler. The last example interprets the stack and is capable of writing the name of a function, which segfaults.

Answer (score 5):

When `glibc` debuginfo is installed (e.g. on Fedora 22: `dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.21-5.fc22.x86_64`) one can print out the `main_arena` and `mp_`.

The output for a core dump of a program which malloced one time 1000 bytes and one time 200000 bytes is as follows:

```
(gdb) p main_arena.system_mem
$3 = 135168
(gdb) p main_arena.max_system_mem
$4 = 135168
(gdb) p mp_
$5 = {trim_threshold = 131072, top_pad = 131072, mmap_threshold = 131072, arena_test = 8, arena_max = 0, n_mmaps = 1, 
  n_mmaps_max = 65536, max_n_mmaps = 1, no_dyn_threshold = 0, mmapped_mem = 200704, max_mmapped_mem = 200704, 
  max_total_mem = 0, sbrk_base = 0x1ace000 ""}
(gdb)
```

That means that total heap size is 135168 bytes including the free memory chunks. This is also the maximum ever reached value.
Memory mapped memory is 200704 bytes, 200000 bytes rounded up to 196 kB.

Answer (score 4):

You can see some information about the heap using `info proc mappings`.

Finding the number of instances of a given class is trickier.  By itself, gdb doesn't know anything about the heap layout of your application.  You are left to explore it on your own.

However, there are some tools to help.  A good place to start is the [gdb-heap project](https://github.com/rogerhu/gdb-heap), which teaches gdb about how glibc manages the heap.  From this could you find allocations and examine vtable pointers to find instances of objects -- at least objects that have vtables.  I don't think there is any generic way to find instances of other kinds of objects.

gdb-heap may need some hacking to be usable for your purposes.

Comment: Then there is no way to get this info by using gdb directly. I'd have to use some external tool besides gdb.

Comment: gdb-heap is a tool that runs inside of gdb.  It's a bunch of Python scripts.  But yes, gdb by itself does not know about the details of how malloc works.

Comment: I'm working on solaris environment and I've just discovered `mdb` You can use it to analyze a core dump and a `findleaks` command  exists but I am not able to run it because of problems with system libraries. If I get it works I´ll post how to use it

Comment: isn't gdb-heap Python-only? Haven't tried it, but it seems so from project's page.